# Highlight combobox text on click in Oracle jet

Tags: jquery, oracle-jet

I want to highlight the text when click on combobox.
This is JQuery example
http://jsfiddle.net/Ilmv/5zWad/

I would like to do the same on my combobox, but it is not working.
Oracle jet expands their components at run time to add their own classes. So, I am confused on which id or class I need to apply.

This is my editable combobox.

```
 <input id="combobox" class="seriescombobox" list="series"
     data-bind="ojComponent:{component:'ojCombobox',value:seriesValue,
               optionChange:LoadSerieses(), 
               rootAttributes: {style:'min-width:32em'}}"/>
     <datalist id="series">
           <!-- ko foreach: serieses -->
               <option data-bind ="value:value,text:label">
               </option>
           <!-- /ko -->
     </datalist>
```

This is the JQuery code I am using to highlight the text.

```
      $(".oj-combobox-input").focus();
      $(".oj-combobox-input").select();
```

I tried with all possible ids and classes but no luck.
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: possible to generate a fiddle with the oracle jet combobox example?

Comment: Were you able to connect the combobox to your JS function on an onclick event? I mean, is $(".oj-combobox-input").focus() getting invoked or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked finally.

This will make text to highlight when click on the combobox.

```
$(".oj-combobox-input").attr('onclick','this.select()');
```

Once you mouse up focus will gone. Below line is to keep the text highlight.

```
$(".oj-combobox-input").attr('onmouseup','return false');
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect your combobox to a JavaScript function using `optionChange` attribute.
I noticed that even if you call the element.select, ojet kind of refreshes the combo and the value gets deselected. To overcome this, in you JS callback write the select code so that it executes after a slight delay, may be you can use setTimeout. Not the best way, but this will work.

```
valueChangeHandler = function(event) {
            setTimeout(function() { $('#oj-combobox-input-combobox_1')[0].select()}, 200);
        };
```

Note that I am using an id here to get the text component. In your case the id would be `"oj-combobox-input-" + id of the combobox`